# Как сделать перезапуск spring?

Tags: java, spring, docker-compose

Использую spring с docker-compose. Мне нужно чтобы при падении контейнера spring он перезапускался, определенное кол-во раз. Как это сделать?

Comment: Вам нужно именно "определенное количество раз" или подойдет "всегда, когда происходит ошибка"? См. on-failure -- https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#restart

Comment: @SlavaSemushin, Определенное. "всегда" у меня работает. а с определенным количеством не работает. on-failure пробовал писать: on-failure: 3,on-failure: "3",on-failure (3),on-failure 3, и много как по другому. Но в любом случаи возникает ошибка. А пример когда через файл я не нашел